# How can I rotate two divs to form an X when I click the container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I have now: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sturv/4AUmB/)

this is the html

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="line1" class="line"></div>
    <div id="line2" class="line"></div>
    <div id="line3" class="line"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to rotate line1 and line3 to form an X and make line2 disappear when you click the container div (#box). I like the idea of jQuery because of Animation, but any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: I don't know if that suits you, but I'll go for CSS transitions and minor style modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/4AUmB/2/.

Comment: Coincidentally, Starbucks uses the same thing for their mobile menu also.  Here's someone's [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/willdages/pen/vsHEA) showing how to reverse it as well.

Comment: I did exaclty the same effect some time ago and found the pen, you can take a look at it here : http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/LFmte click on the menu icon to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/QxL67/)

```
.rotateL{
    transform:rotate(45deg) translateX(10px);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translateX(10px);
    transform-origin:30%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:30%;
}

.rotateR{
    transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(10px);
    transform-origin:22%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:22%;
}
```